# What's is this called and how can I do this?

Tags: android, listview

Attached I have a picture of what I want to do, but I have no idea what it's called, making it very hard to ask the right question or search for the answer. [image]

I want to make it so that when an item in my listview is clicked, a small little drop down will appear, able to show the user a little note. I have no idea what to call that drop down or how to implement something like this in my code. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: ExpandableListView https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: That's called as ExpandableListView. Check out this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) for more info.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=doodle&biw=1067&bih=542&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjzrsGgwPPNAhVLL8AKHbYbDpwQ_AUIBigB

Comment: Perfect. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the comments above, what I was looking for is known as an ExpandableListView.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13010683)

Comment: @KirilS. how does this not answer the question? I asked the question and I feel that the people in the comments answered it.